# Any way to search for a single word in a list in a single cell? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm very new to pretty much everything, I only started using functions in the past couple of months.

I started a new mini project and I need to sum up a bunch of selections from a Google form. The question is are checkboxes and the issue is all the answers are put into the single cell separated by a comma and a space. Each word carries its own value that needs to be summed so I need a way of checking if each answer was checked.

My attempt at doing this was having an extra cell for each possible answer and have it check (using =lookup) if that single cell had answer checked. But unfortunately it said it didn't detect it each time.

The only other solution I could think of is creating an IFS statement for each possible combination of answers but with almost 40 options, that's going to take ages lol

If there's a way to do this using a formula or even creating a script for it then any ideas would be appreciated <3

[image]

Comment: Then what output expect from given image?

Comment: I think you need to use wildcards for this, to check if the cell **contains** the single word you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `find` formula can give you some workload release?

```
=if(IFERROR(FIND(E19,B19),0)>0,"Found","Not Exist")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much

Comment: Welcome, accept the answer if solve your issue :)